# Peut-on employer Monsieur pour parler d'un mort ?

Tags: usage, société

J'ai récemment lu quelqu'un soutenir qu'on ne doit pas parler des morts avec la civilité « Monsieur Boisson » ou « Madame Boisson ».
Il argue que cela serait contraire à l'usage, et que l'on doit utiliser le seul nom de famille (« Boisson »), ou y adjoindre le prénom (« Jean Boisson », « Éléonore Boisson »).

Cette règle a-t-elle existé, et est-elle encore de rigueur ? Avez-vous une référence ?

Comment: Il m'arrive d'entendre feu Monsieur...

Answer (score 12):

Oui, cette règle a déjà existé et est encore en usage, du moins dans certaines parties de la francophonie. Le gouvernement du Canada, par [Termium](http://www.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_m&page=1594.html#zz1571), offre ceci :

> **Monsieur** ou **Madame**, suivi du nom ou du titre, ne s’emploient que pour une personne vivante. En parlant du patrimoine transmis par une personne décédée, il faudrait donc dire *la succession de Jean Chénier, d’Amanda Tremblay*.

Bien que ce ne sont pas des sources considérées crédibles, plusieurs forums de discussions que j'ai lu abondaient dans le même sens.

Si l'on considère que l'on utilise *monsieur* et *madame* pour s'adresser, directement ou indirectement, à la personne en question, cet usage est très sensé.

Comment: Il est d'ailleurs amusant de penser que l'adjectif possessif "ma" de "madame" ou "mon" de "monsieur" provient d'un rapport féodal d'appartenance. Super, le titre !

Answer (score 4):

Lorsque la mort concerne l'aspect juridique, ce sont les usages du droit qui l'emportent, comme l'on dit *l'affaire X* ou *X* est le nom d'un mis en cause, on parlera de *la succession Y*, car seul le patrimoine est concerné.

En revanche, lorsque l'on parle d'une personne disparue,

- pour un proche le prénom suffit : *À la mort de Jean, elle a sombré
  dans une mélancolie profonde*.
- Pour parler de quelqu'un, prénom et nom sont nécessaires, sans autre titre, d'un acteur par exemple : *À la mort de Jean Yanne, l'humour était en berne*.
- La noblesse, le clergé aime bien les honneurs : on parle encore *du Cardinal  Mazarin*. Titre et nom seulement, peu de gens savent que c'était un *Jules*.
- Lorsque la mort vient d'arriver, on ne cite souvent seulement le titre : *Le roi (le pape) est mort ; ton grand-père vient de mourir*

Answer (score 3):

En français classique, Monsieur, Madame, Mademoiselle (curieusement, pas de Mondamoiseau) étaient obligatoires et suivi éventuellement du titre pour désigner un vivant ; puis feu Monsieur, feue Madame pendant un an ; et enfin, seulement titre et nom.
Monsieur, Madame, utilisés absolument, désignaient le frère ou la sœur du roi ; "Madame se meurt ! Madame est morte !" s'est exclamé Monsieur ( = évêque) de Meaux.
Les gens du peuple se désignaient par le simple nom, souvent le prénom, ou par un sobriquet.

Actuellement, on ne donne que le nom d'un personnage très connu (fonction importante, auteur ou acteur célèbre), ou alors pour le dénigrer ensuite. Ou au contraire, une personne connue dans l'entourage, comme un voisin, ce serait froid ou obséquieux.

"Ce Monsieur" frise l'insulte.